# Image Asset versus Vector Asset

Tags: image, android-studio, icons, android-assets

[image: immage]

When it comes to adding an icon to my app, there're two main options:

> IMAGE ASSET || IMAGE VECTOR

What are the differences between the Image Asset and Vector Asset? What makes them different?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

According to Android User Guide :

[Image Asset Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/image-asset-studio.html) helps you create various types of icons at different densities and shows you exactly where they'll be placed in your project. It includes tools for adjusting your icons and adding backdrops, all while displaying the result in a preview pane, so they appear exactly as you intended.

[Vector Asset Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/vector-asset-studio.html#about) adds a vector graphic to the project as an XML file that describes the image. Maintaining one XML file can be easier than updating multiple raster graphics at various resolutions.

Comment: I this case look like you don't will never use assets because vector is better, right?

Answer (score 0):

When you create an image asset it will automatically create a vector graphic that describes that image as an xml file in the drawable..thus you can maintain that one xml file of your image rather than update it in multiple graphics and resolutions.
When you create a vector asset you simply create an xml file that describes an image/graphic in the drawables.